# Is using the BigInteger probablePrime function safe for RSA encryption?

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, biginteger

I have written a code that is able to generate 2048 bit prime p & q's and use that to encrypt messages in RSA. The way I generate these numbers is by using the java.math.BigInteger package's probablePrime() function. My question is how strong of an encryption these function generated prime numbers are in terms of encryption.

Here is my code for generating these numbers, isPrime is just a boolean function I wrote to check if the number is prime.

```
BigInteger definitePrime(int bits, Random rnd) {
  BigInteger prime = new BigInteger("4");
  while (!isPrime (prime)) {
    prime = BigInteger.probablePrime(bits, rnd);
  }
  return prime;
}
```

Comment: I don't mean to doubt your programming skills, but are you claiming you have written a method that can efficiently test whether the values returned by `BigInteger.probablePrime(2048, new Random())` are prime?

Comment: You should use a do/while loop here, to avoid the initialization and the redundant first test.

Comment: Yes, it's a for loop that runs from i = 2 and continues for as long as i is less that the square root of the number. It then takes the number mod i and if the value is zero it returns false. If it runs through the loop without a num%i resulting in zero it returns true. It's a very effective method for checking if the number is prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Stephen C points out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29584454), the primes are probably ok for RSA encryption.

## Cryptographic randomness

I would add, that you shouldn't actually use any `Random` instance, but only your systems best `SecureRandom` implementation.

`new Random()` is not a cryptographic randomness source, whereas `new SecureRandom()` should be. If the random numbers that are used for prime generation are not cryptographically secure, then an attacker may have a chance to simply recreate those based on other information (such as time or previous outputs of the weak randomness source).

## No Textbook RSA

You're doing "everything" yourself and it seems that you actually want to use this for serious encryption. If you are, you're missing something crucial and that is the padding scheme.

It is easy to use the `BigInteger` methods to implement RSA so that it works, but it's not enough to make it secure. You *need* to use a padding scheme like PKCS#1 v1.5 (not recommended anymore) or PKCS#1 v2 OAEP (recommended).

## Use existing implementations

Instead of implementing those padding schemes for your "handmade" RSA, use Java's [`Cipher` instance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) which provides RSA with those padding schemes:

- `RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding`
- `RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding`

Comment: I am only doing this for fun. However I would like to thank you for your input and I will definitely look into padding schemes.

Comment: Do you really need padding if your inputs and outputs are big integers that you don't need to convert to bytes and strings? What to pad in this case?

Comment: @OlegGryb Padding is only necessary for security. If you don't care about security and a mixture of security and obfuscation is enough for you, then you can skip padding. Since the padding is usually applied in binary form, you would have to convert the input to bytes, then add padding (hopefully OAEP), convert it back to BigInteger and perform the remaining steps as Textbook RSA. I would advise not to implement RSA or some RSA padding yourself. Maybe you're opening up the implementation to side-channel attacks or easy cryptanalysis.

Comment: @Artjom B. You didn't read my qs. Input is already a big integer. What are you going to pad and how in this case? Yet another important detail - it's less than the size of the key.

Comment: @OlegGryb It seems you didn't read my response. Yes, you need padding if you want security. It doesn't have anything to do with whether you have `byte[]` or `BigInteger`. If you have a `BigInteger` and you have a padding function that uses `byte[]` then you have to convert it to `byte[]`. The input to RSA must be padded.

Comment: @Artjom B. There is no 100% in anything. Even with OAEP, which is semantically better than PKCSv1.5, would you say that OAEP/SHA1 (let alone PKCSv1.5) is not secure and everybody should use OAEP/SHA256?  Saying that something is secure or not secure doesn't tell much. It would be nice to see how many brute-forcing attempts are required to break RSA vs RSA/PKCS1.5 vs RSA/OAEP/SHA1 vs RSA/OAEP/SHA256. For AES 128 or 256 I've seen the numbers. If you have any for RSA, please share. Security is a comparative thing.

Comment: @OlegGryb Right, security is assessed when compared to other mechanisms. I can't point you to a resource that shows how many CPU years are necessary to brute force textbook RSA, RSA with PKCS1.5 padding and with OAEP. I know that textbook RSA is considered insufficient by cryptographers from the first years on as RSA was conceived. Textbook RSA might be OK, if the plaintext is randomly selected, but it doesn't have to be secure. PKCS 1.5 padding has received much attention in recent years with multiple nails in the coffin. OAEP did not despite being also quite old.

Comment: ... OAEP can use two different hash functions. As I recall from discussions on [crypto.se] when SHA1 was broken two years ago, SHA1 for MGF was still ok, but SHA1 for hashing was not.

Comment: @Artjom B. Nailing coffins is a forward looking thing. It's been a while since 3DES and CBC have been called "insecure", but reality is that industry is not even close to getting rid of 3DES, and nobody seriously considers removing CBC in existing apps. If you swipe your card at an older terminal, the chances are very high that 3DES is used. Nobody stops using cards because of that. SHA1 is still OK in cases like PBKDF/SAH1 and OAEP/SHA1, so  security should be evaluated against use cases to avoid unnecessary spending.

Answer (score 1):

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#nextProbablePrime--) for `BigInteger.probablePrime()` says:

> Returns a positive BigInteger that is probably prime, with the specified bitLength. The probability that a BigInteger returned by this method is composite *does not exceed* 2<sup>-100</sup>.

2<sup>-100</sup> means one chance in 1,267,650,600,228,229,401,496,703,205,376; i.e. 1 chance in ~1.267 * 10<sup>30</sup>

Since you are trying to generating 2 primes, that means that you have 2 chances in roughly 10<sup>30</sup> of generating a weak RSA key pair.

I'd have thought that that was good enough, but if you don't think so then you could use `BigInteger.isProbablePrime(certainty)` to test your prime candidates to an even higher level of certainty.

---

> My question is how strong of an encryption these function generated prime numbers are in terms of encryption.

I don't know if there is a mathematically rigorous way to quantify the strength of an encryption algorithm.  But the above analysis tells you the probability that a given generated key-pair will be weak / easy to crack.

Comment: Thank you for your input, this is definitely enough probability for me

Answer (score -1):

The generated primes are not secure if you use something like java.util.Random instead of an instance of SecureRandom. Your code snippet does not tell us what you are using, hence it is not possible to validate your code. Of course, you probably should just use JCE to generate new RSA keys.